# Android WebView scale(decrease height) when the fragment(AdMob) scales (increases height)

Tags: android-layout, android-fragments, admob

The following is the layout file. The inner relative layout **(id=webViewLayout)** will contain a **WebView** which is added to the layout at runtime and the fragment's **(id=adFragement)** height is 0 when the app starts, since no ads are loaded. At this point the **WebView** inside the **id=webViewLayout** takes up all the space on the screen and when later the ads are fetched and the the **id=adFragment** displays ads its height is 50. The ads are projected on top of the **WebView**.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/webViewLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/adFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/adFragment"
        android:name="com.gatta.e.gatta.MainActivity$AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_ad"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

How to make the **WebView** to decrease the scaling dynamically when the **fragment's** height gets increased. ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `LinearLayout` instead, so you have access to the `android:layout_weight` property.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/webViewLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/adFragment"
    android:name="com.gatta.e.gatta.MainActivity$AdFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_ad" />
```

Comment: The behaviour is the same . no change.